# How to pipe a data-stream (in this case SQL) into a docker/podman container needing multiple commands in the exec command line?

Tags: mysql, docker, pipe, exec, podman

I'm trying to restore mysql databases backed up to `file.sql.gz` with mysqldump in a new mariadb container instance running under podman (or docker, which works the same). 
Since I also don't have (or want) mysql client on the host, and this container doesn't have gzip, my idea was to pipe the unzipped sql into an exec command on the running container and into mysql like this:

```
gzip -dc  MyMusic72.sql.gz | podman exec mariadb bash -c 'cat - | /usr/bin/mysql -u root -pmypasswd'
```

This doesn't seem to work, however, because `bash -c` apparently doesn't forward `STDIN`? But at the same time I seem to need `bash -c` to have the whole command line interpreted as part of the podman `exec` command...

(Of course I could gunzip the SQL files and mount their location in the container, but it surely must be possible to do this in one step?)

Any ideas?

Comment: To use _STDIN_, you need to give the flag `-i` to podman.

Comment: @ErikSjölund Thanks! (better late than never ;) I'll try next time wether I can make it work with that.